# concat of strings echos in wrong order

Tags: php, string-concatenation

I have a class

```
$page=new page;
```

with function,

```
header() {
echo 'blah blah';
}
```

now if I concat two strings together like,

```
$string= "";
$string .= " 1234";
$string .= $page->header();
echo $string;
```

results in,

```
blah blah 1234
```

how can I get it in the correct order?

Comment: `echo` is immediate output. it's not a function, it has no return value, it literally outputs whatever it's told RIGHT THEN AND THERE. So the echo you do in your `header()` call executes first, THEN you echo the rest of $string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just echoing the string.

your `header()` function should return a string:

```
function header() {
    return 'blah blah';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `echo` statement in the function is executed immediately upon the calling of that function. That's why you see it first. If you want to append it to as string you need to *return* that value:

```
public function header() {
    return 'blah blah';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning a value for the string concatenation in your function, you're simply echoing "blah blah". Your code is equivalent to:

```
$string = "";
$string .= "1234";
echo "blah blah";
$string .= "";
echo $string;
```

You need to return a string from your function to use in concatenation like:

```
function header() { return "blah blah"; }
```